Sending file from Raspberry Pi Pico to voice recognition API
I have a project of a bedside lamp with a voice assistant using special requests. I have this code on my PC :
import os
import shutil
import time
import requests
import speech_recognition as sr
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from gtts import gTTS
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

app = FastAPI()

api_key = "APIKEY"
base_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
city_name = "tunis"


def get_meteo():
    complete_url = base_url + "appid=" + api_key + "&q=" + city_name + "&lang=fr"
    response = requests.get(complete_url)
    x = response.json()

    if x["cod"] != "404":
        y = x["main"]
        current_temperature_kelvin = y["temp"]
        current_temperature_celsius = current_temperature_kelvin - 273.15
        z = x["weather"]
        weather_description = z[0]["description"]
        return f"Il fait {current_temperature_celsius:.2f} degrés Celsius à {city_name}. La météo est {weather_description}."
    else:
        return "City Not Found"


def decision(text):
    greeting_detected = False
    polite_detected = False

    if any(word in text for word in ["bonjour", "salut", "coucou"]):
        greeting_detected = True
    if any(word in text for word in ["s'il te plaît", "s'il vous plaît", "svp"]):
        polite_detected = True

    if greeting_detected or polite_detected:
        # Si une salutation ou une politesse est détectée, chercher une vraie requête dans la phrase originale
        real_request = find_real_request(text)
        if real_request:
            return real_request
        else:
            return "Je n'ai pas compris votre requête. Si vous voulez vérifier quelles requêtes sont acceptées dans cette version de AVD, consultez notre site web"
    else:
        if any(word in text for word in ["allume la lumière", "allume toi", "allume la lampe", "ouvre la lumière", "ouvre toi", "ouvre la lampe", "lumos", "lumos maxima", "jour"]):
            return "allume"
        elif any(word in text for word in ["eteinds la lumière", "éteinds la lumière", "éteinds toi", "eteinds toi", "ferme la lumière", "ferme toi", "éteinds la lampe", "eteinds la lampe", "nox", "nuit"]):
            return "eteinds"
        elif any(word in text for word in ["quel heure est-il", "quelle heure est-il", "donne moi l'heure", "donne moi l'heure s'il te plaît", "avd, quel heure est-il", "avd, quelle heure est-il", "avd, donne moi l'heure", "avd, donne moi l'heure s'il te plaît", "donne moi l'heure stp", "donne moi l'heure svp", "avd, donne moi l'heure stp", "avd, donne moi l'heure svp", "avd quel heure est-il", "avd quelle heure est-il", "avd donne moi l'heure", "avd donne moi l'heure s'il te plaît", "avd donne moi l'heure stp", "avd donne moi l'heure svp"]):
            return get_time()
        elif any(word in text for word in ["quel temps fait-il", "quelle temps fait-il", "donne moi la meteo", "donne moi la meteo s'il te plaît", "avd, quel temps fait-il", "avd, quelle temps fait-il", "avd, donne moi la meteo", "avd, donne moi la meteo s'il te plaît", "donne moi l'heure stp", "donne moi l'heure svp", "avd, donne moi l'heure stp", "avd, donne moi l'heure svp", "avd quel heure est-il", "avd quelle heure est-il", "avd donne moi l'heure", "avd donne moi l'heure s'il te plaît", "avd donne moi l'heure stp", "avd donne moi l'heure svp"]):
            return get_meteo()
        else:
            return "Je n'ai pas compris votre requête. Si vous voulez vérifier quelles requêtes sont acceptées dans cette version de AVD, consultez notre site web"

def find_real_request(text):
    real_request = text.replace("bonjour", "").replace("salut", "").replace("coucou", "").replace("s'il te plaît", "").replace("s'il vous plaît", "").replace("svp", "").strip()
    if any(word in real_request for word in
           ["allume la lumière", "allume toi", "allume la lampe", "ouvre la lumière", "ouvre toi", "ouvre la lampe",
            "lumos", "lumos maxima", "jour"]):
        return "allume"
    elif any(word in real_request for word in
             ["eteinds la lumière", "éteinds la lumière", "éteinds toi", "eteinds toi", "ferme la lumière", "ferme toi",
              "éteinds la lampe", "eteinds la lampe", "nox", "nuit"]):
        return "eteinds"
    elif any(word in real_request for word in
             ["quel heure est-il", "quelle heure est-il", "donne moi l'heure", "donne moi l'heure s'il te plaît",
              "avd, quel heure est-il", "avd, quelle heure est-il", "avd, donne moi l'heure",
              "avd, donne moi l'heure s'il te plaît", "donne moi l'heure stp", "donne moi l'heure svp",
              "avd, donne moi l'heure stp", "avd, donne moi l'heure svp", "avd quel heure est-il",
              "avd quelle heure est-il", "avd donne moi l'heure", "avd donne moi l'heure s'il te plaît",
              "avd donne moi l'heure stp", "avd donne moi l'heure svp"]):
        return get_time()
    elif any(word in real_request for word in
             ["quel temps fait-il", "quelle temps fait-il", "donne moi la meteo", "donne moi la meteo s'il te plaît",
              "avd, quel temps fait-il", "avd, quelle temps fait-il", "avd, donne moi la meteo",
              "avd, donne moi la meteo s'il te plaît", "donne moi l'heure stp", "donne moi l'heure svp",
              "avd, donne moi l'heure stp", "avd, donne moi l'heure svp", "avd quel heure est-il",
              "avd quelle heure est-il", "avd donne moi l'heure", "avd donne moi l'heure s'il te plaît",
              "avd donne moi l'heure stp", "avd donne moi l'heure svp"]):
        return get_meteo()
    else:
        return "Je n'ai pas compris votre requête. Si vous voulez vérifier quelles requêtes sont acceptées dans cette version de AVD, consultez notre site web"


def get_time():
    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M", t)
    return f"Il est {current_time} à {city_name}."


def save_file(file):
    with open(file.filename, "wb") as buffer:
        shutil.copyfileobj(file.file, buffer)


@app.get("/")
async def main():
    content = """
    <body>
    <form action="/upload/" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input name="file" type="file" multiple>
    <button type="submit">Transcrire</button>
    </form>
    </body>
    """
    return HTMLResponse(content=content)


@app.post("/upload")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    save_file(file)
    recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
    audio_file = sr.AudioFile(file.filename)
    with audio_file as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio_data = recognizer.record(source)
    try:
        text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio_data, language="fr-FR").lower()
        print("Text extracted from audio:", text)  # Debugging
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        text = "Impossible de reconnaître la parole"
    except sr.RequestError:
        text = "Erreur lors de la requête à l'API de reconnaissance vocale"

    response_text = decision(text)
    if response_text is not None:
        tts = gTTS(text=response_text, lang='fr')
        tts.save("response.mp3")

        audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3("response.mp3")
        play(audio)

        os.remove("response.mp3")
    else:
        response_text = "Je n'ai pas compris votre requête. Si vous voulez vérifier quelles requêtes sont acceptées dans cette version de AVD, consultez notre site web"

    os.remove(file.filename)

    return response_text

And I have this code on my Raspberry Pi Pico :
import utime
import uos
import urandom
import struct
from machine import Pin, ADC
import urequests

API_URL = "http://192.168.1.114:8000/upload"

MICROPHONE_PIN = 28
RECORDING_DURATION = 5
SAMPLE_RATE = 16000  
CHUNK_SIZE = 1024  

def write_wav_header(f, num_samples):
    data_size = num_samples * 2  
    header = struct.pack('<4sI4s4sIHHIIHH4sI',
                         b'RIFF', data_size + 36, b'WAVE', b'fmt ', 16, 1, 1,
                         SAMPLE_RATE, SAMPLE_RATE * 2, 2, 16, b'data', data_size)
    f.write(header)

def check_storage():
    stats = uos.statvfs('/')
    free_space = stats[0] * stats[3]
    print(f"Espace libre: {free_space} octets")
    return free_space

def record_audio(filename):
    print("Enregistrement audio en cours...")
    adc = ADC(Pin(MICROPHONE_PIN))
    num_samples = SAMPLE_RATE * RECORDING_DURATION

    if check_storage() < num_samples * 2 + 44:  
        print("Erreur: Espace de stockage insuffisant.")
        return False

    try:
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            write_wav_header(f, num_samples)
            start_time = utime.time()
            for _ in range(num_samples):
                sample = adc.read_u16() - 32768  
                f.write(struct.pack('<h', sample))
        print(f"Fichier enregistré: {filename}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur lors de la sauvegarde du fichier: {e}")
        return False

def send_audio(filename):
    print("Envoi de l'audio à l'API...")
    
    try:
        with open(filename, "rb") as f:
            chunk = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
            if chunk:
                headers = {"Content-Type": "audio/wav"}
                response = urequests.post(API_URL, data=chunk, headers=headers)
                while chunk:
                    chunk = f.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
                    if chunk:
                        response = urequests.post(API_URL, data=chunk, headers=headers)
                
                print("Réponse de l'API:", response.status_code, response.text)
                response.close()
            else:
                print(f"Erreur: Le fichier {filename} est vide.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Erreur lors de la lecture ou de l'envoi du fichier: {e}")

def main():
    try:
        filename = "recording_" + str(urandom.randint(1, 1000000)) + ".wav"
        
        if record_audio(filename):
            send_audio(filename)
        
            try:
                uos.remove(filename)
                print(f"Fichier supprimé: {filename}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Erreur lors de la suppression du fichier: {e}")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Une erreur s'est produite:", repr(e))

main()



But when it sends the file I have this error in the Thonny console :
Enregistrement audio en cours...
Espace libre: 860160 octets
Fichier enregistré: recording_114328.wav
Envoi de l'audio à l'API...
Erreur lors de la lecture ou de l'envoi du fichier: [Errno 104] ECONNRESET
Fichier supprimé: recording_114328.wav
And this one in the uvicorn console :
INFO:     192.168.1.129:62904 - "POST /upload HTTP/1.0" 422 Unprocessable Entity
I tried a lot of things like converting to wav or other.
